# Cannot Login in SQL Server Management Studio, Error: 233

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I changed authentication mode from "Windows Authentication" to "Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication" and also enabled "sa" user and changed it's password and defined another user.

But now when I want to login in SQL Server Management Studio, it will show me this error:
[image]

- I restarted SQL services
- I restarted windows
- I changed authentication mode from windows registry (because I couldn't login and change it in Properties)

Comment: Try connecting with tcp/ip instead of named pipes (its an option somewhere in the login dialog)

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should login with windows auth. again and you should change sa user permission in roles as system admin. at the end of this process you should restart again sql service in services.

Comment: I can login neither with windows auth nor sql auth. In any way I cannot login in ssms. Also my sharepoint portal doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't login because you have a bad setting of your sa user, so for fix this problem you have to do this

[image]

So you can login now. Then enter to properties of the server in the security page check windows authentication y also verify connection page and set to the default